# How do I get all for-looped values from a Django template

Tags: python, django

I am new to django. I want to use this django form to get number_of_days for all {{ name }} values

```
<div>
    <form action="change_number_of_days" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
             {% for name in filenames %}

                     <input type="number" name="number_of_days" id="number_of_days" value=200>
                     <label for="number_of_days"> {{ name }} </label>
                     <input type="hidden" value="{{ name }}" name="name_of_file"><br><br>

             {% endfor %}
         <button type="submit"> Gem </button>
     </form>
</div>
```

[image: This is what the template looks like]

Currently Im only getting the values of the LAST loop(Pizzaria, 200), but I want to get all looped inputs as a POST request

This is my VIEW.py

```
def change_number_of_days(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        days = request.POST['number_of_days']
        print(cleaning_days)
        filename = request.POST['name_of_file']
        print(filename)

        return render(request, 'price_calculation_complete.html')

    return HttpResponse("error")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have explicitly mentioned that - That's why it shows only 200

```
<input type="number" name="number_of_days" id="number_of_days" value=200>
```

You have to set the first `<input>` tag's value to `{{ name }}`.

```html
<div>
    <form action="change_number_of_days" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
             {% for name in filenames %}

                     <input type="number" name="number_of_days" id="number_of_days" value="{{ name }}">
                     <label for="number_of_days"> {{ name }} </label>
                     <input type="hidden" value="200" name="name_of_file"><br><br>

             {% endfor %}
         <button type="submit"> Gem </button>
     </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Im using the value="200" to set a default value of all iterations in the forloop.
The problem is not the input I recieve, but that I only get the LAST looped input. And not all 4. I need to get values(number_of_days & name_of_file) of all 4 iterations

Comment: If you wish to use a default value , you have to use 200 as value in the hidden ```<input>```. Check my updated answer.

Comment: When using your method the default value for all input fields disappear. The problem is that I only get values from the last iteration instead of all 4

Comment: OK. Could you explain what those two ```<input>``` are for ? Where do you expect the default value to show up? Is it in ```number_of_days``` or ```name_of_file``` ?

Comment: I have posted a picture of what the HTML looks like in the post. It should look excactly like that. The problem is when I press the "Gem"(which means Save) button, I only get the last two values which in this example would be "200" and "Pizzaria". 
I also need to get "200" and "Amager", "200" and "Arnolds", "200" and "DR byer" back to my views.py. Like a list[] object

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. To anyone interested:

days_list = request.POST.getlist('number_of_cleaning_days')

I had to use .getlist instead of just POST